# Is it a good idea to Hardcode something like a ListView/RecyclerView in android?

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, hardcode, hardcoded

I want something like a ListView/RecyclerView with cards, all the text and image are available locally. Considering all this, is it a good idea to Hardcode the layout with cards and setting text and images in XML only?

Comment: If its all available locally you can still use it provided you think thats the viable design choice for your content. if you have design and content such tht it needs to be in a listview/recyclerview, then use it that way and there is no harm in that.

Comment: @KapilG do you mean that Hard-coding don't slowdown the Application or something?